# This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I've been trying constantly now to get google maps for android V2 to work.
I'm trying this on device : Samsung Galaxy S [2.3.3] and on emulators.

My manifest:
(I've tried using both Debug key and Release key)

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.klottr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.klottr.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.example.klottr.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDqmCXjO-h-Yy_qGsyVrUz_icB9mCTUzLM"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.klottr.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The mainactivity xml:

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".MainActivity" >

         <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The mainactivity java file:

```
package com.example.klottr;

import com.example.klottr.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

}
```

I've tried following the guide on the google website, and several guides and tricks from stackoverflow. I'd more than appreciate some tips. 
I'm just trying to get my device to show the map correctly at the moment, but instead I get
"This app won't run unless you update Google Play Services" , Even though the latest version of Google Play Services is installed on my device.

Comment: how do you have the google play services library linked into the project?

Comment: Import existing android code into workspace (/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib)
Right click project -> Properties -> Android -> Add -> Select the google play service library

Comment: do you also see the google play jar under both Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies? I'm asking because I'm basically having the same issue, and I'm seeing that. Not sure that's correct or not, but doesn't seem to be any way to not have it. Also, are you copying the project into the workspace when you import?

Comment: Copy project into workspace : Yes

Actually in Android Private libraries:
google-play-services.jar (located ../google-play-services_lib/libs

In Android Dependancies:
google-play-services_lib.jar  (located ../google-play-services_lib/bin

Comment: how about order and export tab? And, to be clear, you're not seeing the jar under Adnroid Dependencies, just Android Private Libraries, correct? Wait, never mind, just reread your comment, duh. sorry

Comment: In Order & Export Tab, both Android Dependencies and Android Private Libraries are checked. 
This might be the problem since it seems to be 2 different jars?

Comment: I'm not sure, honestly. I can't get mine to run from within eclipse, even though it appears to build fine. But when I try to run it, I get the dreaded Out of Memory...can't convert to Dalvyk... error, and I think seems like the most likely candidate as I don't see any other build path issues. To work around running from eclipse, I built with ant, and then hit the same problem you're getting. Hopefully we can figure it out

Answer (score 7):

Google updated google_play_service library, but not the Play Services app in the google play.
So I suggest you to download **"Google play services for Froyo"** in the Android SDK Manager and plug it to the project instead of the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue 1: READ_GSERVICES not present in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Link: http://t1685.codeinpro.us/q/51502052e8432c04261af736

Possible issue 2: This may just be the namespace of my app but in comparison it may be something to consider

```
<permission android:name="com.fooapp.**androidmapsv2**.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.fooapp.**androidmapsv2**.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Have both in mine. I should point out that my project was working perfectly until a recent update to 22.2 in the sdk manager. Since then, it's all gone to h e double hockey sticks ;-)

Comment: Huh. I did not see the GS Service permission. My mistake.

Comment: Oh no worries at all; thanks so much for replying. Any attempts at a solution are much appreciated.

Comment: I just got it working, from my laptop however.
On my laptop it was showing an empty map with buttons before, could not access to google services, seems like eclipse didnt update the correct path for apikey/fingerprint until I built the project manually. I still don't know why it didn't work with my code above though

Comment: Sorry I cant add comment to your actual solution (lack of rep) but if the emulator does not have "**Google APIs** - API #" set as the target instead of just the "API #" this could cause that problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working on my laptop. The issue on my laptop was however only authorization failure. Seems like my eclipse on the other pc was bugged or something.
The code in the working project is almost exactly the same, with these exceptions:

In the manifest, these lines exist in the working project:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*Test*/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And the only thing in my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Still have no idea why it didn't work from my previous code.
Note: Map is still blank on emulator, but works fine on Samsung Galaxy S 2.3.3 device